# Adding a JPanel to a JFrame changes its size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to make a game, so I decided to create multiple JPanels, which all do something different, so only one JPanel is needed to render everything. To change them, I just do:

```
    this.getContentPane().removeAll();
    CURRENT_CONTENT = new JPanel();
    this.getContentPane().add(CURRENT_CONTENT);
    this.pack();
```

However, when I do this, although the JPanel is appropriately set, it also changes the size of the JFrame by slightly increasing it... How can I stop this from happening?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to design your panels so, that they have the same size. Because the method `pack()` sets the window size accordingly to the size requirements of the content panel. For example you can use the method `setPreferredSize()` that is available for all `JComponent`s

Comment: Do not call pack () method after you add the component. Call it once when the jframe is not even visible.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"To change them .. `removeAll();`"* Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the answers, I got it working!
`pack()` seemed to be the problem.
Here is the final result, in case someone has the same problem:

```
    this.getContentPane().removeAll();
    CURRENT_CONTENT = new JPanel();
    this.getContentPane().add(CURRENT_CONTENT);
    this.revalidate();
```

Thanks again!

Comment: `Here is the final result, in case someone has the same problem:` - You should NOT be setting the preferred size of the panel. It is the job of the layou7t manager to calculate the preferred size of each panel based on the components added to the panel. `the JPanel only appears after the JFrame is resized` - when you add comonents to a visible panel you need to revalidate() the panel. In this case you need to revalidate the content pane of the frame.